# Calculating means for trimesters from an array with monthly values

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, statistics, mean

I have a large array with monthly precipitation values (dimensions=144(longitude)*72(latitude)*395(time)), where time starts at 1979-01-03 (year/month/day) and ends at 2011-11-03.

I need to calculate means and sd, first for each month (i.e. one mean and one sd for each month and each point of the domain). Here's how I did this:

```
months<-c(as.character(1:12))
years<-c(as.character(1979:2011))
lista<-list()
for (i in months){
  lista[[i]]<-which(format(time2,"%m")==i)   #time2 is the time dimension from the 
                                             # array, in format: 1979-01-03, 1979-02-03,etc.
}
monthly_means<-list(); monthly_sd<-list()
for(i in 1:length(lista)){
  medias_mensuales[[i]]<-apply(precipitacion[,,lista[[i]]],c(1,2),mean)
  sd_mensuales[[i]]<-apply(precipitacion[,,lista[[i]]],c(1,2),sd)
}
```

and then (this is where I'm having trouble) the means and sd for each trimester (DJF,MAM,JJA,SON). Is it a good idea to first extract each trimester's data and then do something similar to what I did before?

Comment: Check out  the package`dplyr` using functions `group_by` and `summarize`. see: https://jules32.github.io/2016-07-12-Oxford/dplyr_tidyr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions should include all data but we have provided some for you this time in the Note at the end.   Also the question did not include explanation of what was wanted so we assume that what is wanted is the mean over all January instances for each precip[i, j, ], the mean over all Feb instances and so on all formed into a 3d array in which one dimension is 12.  Similarly for sd and similarly for trimesters.

Define the dates in the last deimnsion of `precip` as `tt` and then define `moy` and `toy` as functions which take a `Date` vector and return the months of the year (numbers from 1 to 12) and trimester quarter of the year (numbers from 1 to 4). These use `yearmon` and `yearqtr` classes which represent dates as year plus fraction and in the case of `toy` 1/12 is added to move Dec into Jan, Jan into Feb, etc. so that the trimester quarters are transformed to calendar quarters.

Using these functions define `cyc12` as a vector of month numbers (1 to 12) and cyc4 as a vector of trimester quarter numbers (1 to 4).  Their values could alternately be expressed as `rep(1:12, length = 395)` and `rep(1:4, each = 3, length = 396)[-1]` .

Using `cyc12` and `cyc4` we use `apply` and `tapply` as shown.

For the first two `apply` instances we get arrays of dimension c(12, 144, 72) and for the last two we get c(4, 144, 72). (If you want permutated dimensions use `aperm`.)

```
library(zoo)

tt <- seq(as.Date("1979-01-03"), as.Date("2011-11-03"), "month")

moy <- function(x) cycle(as.yearmon(x))
cyc12 <- moy(tt)  
means12 <- apply(precip, 1:2, function(x) tapply(x, cyc12, mean))
sd12 <- apply(precip, 1:2, function(x) tapply(x, cyc12, sd))

toy <- function(x) cycle(as.yearqtr(as.yearmon(x) + 1/12))
cyc4 <- toy(tt) 
means4 <- apply(precip, 1:2, function(x) tapply(x, cyc4, mean))
sd4 <- apply(precip, 1:2, function(x) tapply(x, cyc4, sd))
```

### Note

To make this reproducible, assme the input data is as follows

```
Dims <- c(144, 72, 395)
precip <- array(seq_len(prod(Dims)), Dims)
```

Comment: Hey, in  `tt <- seq(as.Date("1979-01-03"), as.Date("2011-11-03"), "day")` shouldn't it be "month" instead of "day" since the array consists of one monthly mean?    After that, I tried with a random point in the domain (lon=30, lat=25) and made sure it doesn't have any NA's, so I did      `sds.mon <- tapply(precipitacion[30,25,], as.yearmon(tt), sd)`   but the result was all (395) NA's. Then I tried with the means    `means.mon <- tapply(precipitacion[30,25,], as.yearmon(tt), mean)`  and the result was the same values I already have, meaning it didn't calculate means. I don't see the error.

Comment: Have completely revised answer.

Comment: Ok, now this worked perfectly, but I would like to understand what is `function(x) tapply(x,.., sd)` actually doing if you don't mind, I mean what is x?

Comment: `x` is the argument to the function.  If you apply that function to a vector `x` it returns the value computed by the function body.  `apply(precip, 1:2, function(x)...)` will apply the anonymous function to the vector `precip[i, j, ]` for each i and j so each time that anonymous function is run `x` equals the vector `precip[i, j, ]` some some values of i and j.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how this is working `function(x) tapply(x, ..., ...)` , what is the function (x)? Is it evaluated in "tapply(x,...,...)"  or is it multiplying or what?

Comment: `apply` takes 3 arguments.  An object, the margins and a function.  `function(x) tapply(x, cyc4, sd)` is the definition of the function that is being passed to `apply`.  It could equally be written as `f <- function(x) tapply(x, cyc4, sd); sd4 <- apply(precip, 1:2, f)` .  so for each i and j apply runs `f(precip[i, j, ])` and then assemblers the outputs into a single object.  If you define `f` as just shown then you can run `f(precip[1, 1, ])` yourself to see its result for particular values of i and j, here 1 and 1.